# smtp errors from dotcloud mail

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta, dotcloud

I am trying to send mail through the dotcloud mailer service, via django.  I am getting this error from my smtp host:

`Helo command rejected: need fully-qualified hostname (in reply to RCPT TO command`

I believe this is because hostname on my server is not fully qualified.  Is this something that can be changed or do I need to change smtp hosts?

I am on a sandbox server at the moment.  Once I am running with a real domain, does that change the hostname setup at all on the dotcloud side?

Comment: So without changing the settings on our smtp server to relax the requirement for a fully qualified hostname, I don't think this setup works.  Instead, we just used mailgun in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **helo** command need to be followed by your domain name.

**for example:**

> helo yahoo.com

Comment: Thank you.  That is good to know.  The question remains as to how to make this change from dotcloud.

Comment: I'm going to select this as answered, as this was the most helpful comment to come in.